# error in converting non-numeric data to numeric

Tags: python

I am trying to change the 'class' values of the iris data set to numeric and i keep getting this error message.

my code is:

```
    import pandas as pd
    df=pd.read_csv('iris_csv.csv')
    df['code']=pd.factorize(df.class)[0]
```

and the error message i get is:

```
File "<ipython-input-4-789c84ab3577>", line 1
df['code']=pd.factorize(df.class)[0]
                           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Can someone help me fix it?

Comment: Why do you think `df` has an attribute called `class`? It can't, since that's a reserved keyword (which is what the error is trying to tell you).

Comment: try `pd.to_numeric` instead and check the docs to for more information, link: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

class is a unique word in python(and lots of others) and you can't use it as a column name as df.class

instead of `df.class` try `df['class']`

to change it to numeric you can copy below line.

```
df['code'] = df['class'].astype(int)
```